# Why does Spark SQL fail, but Spark core works after fresh installation (Scala)?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, visual-studio-code, apache-spark-sql, scala-metals

Why am I able to run Spark core, but not Spark SQL in Scala after fresh installation?

My `build.sbt` looks something like that:

```scala
scalaVersion := "2.13.8"
name := "hello-world"
organization := "ch.epfl.scala"
version := "1.0"

libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-parser-combinators" % "2.1.1"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "3.3.0"
```

and I have a dummy `Main.scala` file with:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext

object Main extends App{
  println("Hello world!")
}
```

Everything works fine, I am even able to perform `import org.apache.spark.SparkContext`. However, as soon as I add `libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "3.3.0"` to `build.sbt`, I get an error:

```
2022.08.28 17:04:01 INFO  running '/home/joris/.jabba/jdk/adopt@1.11.0-11/bin/java -Djline.terminal=jline.UnsupportedTerminal -Dsbt.log.noformat=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar /tmp/metals11626075540729030745/sbt-launch.jar -Dbloop.export-jar-classifiers=sources bloopInstall'
2022.08.28 17:04:03 INFO  [info] welcome to sbt 1.7.1 (AdoptOpenJDK Java 11.0.11)
2022.08.28 17:04:03 INFO  [info] loading settings for project my-hello-world-build-build from metals.sbt ...
2022.08.28 17:04:05 INFO  [info] loading project definition from /media/joris/projects/learn-scala/my-hello-world/project/project
2022.08.28 17:04:05 INFO  [info] loading settings for project my-hello-world-build from metals.sbt ...
2022.08.28 17:04:06 INFO  [info] loading project definition from /media/joris/projects/learn-scala/my-hello-world/project
2022.08.28 17:04:08 INFO  [success] Generated .bloop/my-hello-world-build.json
2022.08.28 17:04:08 INFO  [success] Total time: 2 s, completed Aug 28, 2022, 5:04:08 PM
2022.08.28 17:04:10 INFO  [info] loading settings for project my-hello-world from build.sbt ...
2022.08.28 17:04:10 INFO  [info] set current project to hello-world (in build file:/media/joris/projects/learn-scala/my-hello-world/)
2022.08.28 17:04:12 INFO  [error] Couldn't run bloopGenerate for my-hello-world. Cause:
2022.08.28 17:04:12 INFO  [error] Incomplete(node=Some(Task(_)), tpe=Error, msg=None, causes=List(Incomplete(node=Some(Task(_)), tpe=Error, msg=None, causes=List(Incomplete(node=Some(Task((tags: Map(Tag(update) -> 1, Tag(network) -> 1), taskDefinitionKey: ScopedKey(Scope(Select(ProjectRef(file:/media/joris/projects/learn-scala/my-hello-world/,my-hello-world)), Zero, Zero, Zero),updateClassifiers)))), tpe=Error, msg=None, causes=List(Incomplete(node=Some(Task((taskDefinitionKey: ScopedKey(Scope(Select(ProjectRef(file:/media/joris/projects/learn-scala/my-hello-world/,my-hello-world)), Zero, Select(updateClassifiers), Zero),classifiersModule)))), tpe=Error, msg=None, causes=List(Incomplete(node=Some(Task((taskDefinitionKey: ScopedKey(Scope(Select(ProjectRef(file:/media/joris/projects/learn-scala/my-hello-world/,my-hello-world)), Zero, Zero, Zero),update)))), tpe=Error, msg=None, causes=List(Incomplete(node=Some(Task((tags: Map(Tag(update) -> 1, Tag(network) -> 1), taskDefinitionKey: ScopedKey(Scope(Select(ProjectRef(file:/media/joris/projects/learn-scala/my-hello-world/,my-hello-world)), Zero, Zero, Zero),update)))), tpe=Error, msg=None, causes=List(), directCause=Some(java.lang.RuntimeException: found version conflict(s) in library dependencies; some are suspected to be binary incompatible:
2022.08.28 17:04:12 INFO  [error] 
2022.08.28 17:04:12 INFO  [error] Couldn't run bloopGenerate for my-hello-world-test. Cause:
2022.08.28 17:04:12 INFO  [error]   * org.scala-lang.modules:scala-parser-combinators_2.13:2.1.1 (early-semver) is selected over 1.1.2
2022.08.28 17:04:12 INFO  [error]       +- ch.epfl.scala:hello-world_2.13:1.0                 (depends on 2.1.1)
2022.08.28 17:04:12 INFO  [error] Incomplete(node=Some(Task(_)), tpe=Error, msg=None, causes=List(Incomplete(node=Some(Task(_)), tpe=Error, msg=None, causes=List(Incomplete(node=Some(Task((tags: Map(Tag(update) -> 1, Tag(network) -> 1), taskDefinitionKey: ScopedKey(Scope(Select(ProjectRef(file:/media/joris/projects/learn-scala/my-hello-world/,my-hello-world)), Zero, Zero, Zero),updateClassifiers)))), tpe=Error, msg=None, causes=List(Incomplete(node=Some(Task((taskDefinitionKey: ScopedKey(Scope(Select(ProjectRef(file:/media/joris/projects/learn-scala/my-hello-world/,my-hello-world)), Zero, Select(updateClassifiers), Zero),classifiersModule)))), tpe=Error, msg=None, causes=List(Incomplete(node=Some(Task((taskDefinitionKey: ScopedKey(Scope(Select(ProjectRef(file:/media/joris/projects/learn-scala/my-hello-world/,my-hello-world)), Zero, Zero, Zero),update)))), tpe=Error, msg=None, causes=List(Incomplete(node=Some(Task((tags: Map(Tag(update) -> 1, Tag(network) -> 1), taskDefinitionKey: ScopedKey(Scope(Select(ProjectRef(file:/media/joris/projects/learn-scala/my-hello-world/,my-hello-world)), Zero, Zero, Zero),update)))), tpe=Error, msg=None, causes=List(), directCause=Some(java.lang.RuntimeException: found version conflict(s) in library dependencies; some are suspected to be binary incompatible:
2022.08.28 17:04:12 INFO  [error]       +- org.apache.spark:spark-catalyst_2.13:3.3.0         (depends on 1.1.2)
2022.08.28 17:04:12 INFO  [error] 
2022.08.28 17:04:12 INFO  [error] 
2022.08.28 17:04:12 INFO  [error] this can be overridden using libraryDependencySchemes or evictionErrorLevel))), directCause=None)), directCause=None)), directCause=None)), directCause=None), Incomplete(node=Some(Task((taskDefinitionKey: ScopedKey(Scope(Select(ProjectRef(file:/media/joris/projects/learn-scala/my-hello-world/,my-hello-world)), Zero, Zero, Zero),update)))), tpe=Error, msg=None, causes=List(Incomplete(node=Some(Task((tags: Map(Tag(update) -> 1, Tag(network) -> 1), taskDefinitionKey: ScopedKey(Scope(Select(ProjectRef(file:/media/joris/projects/learn-scala/my-hello-world/,my-hello-world)), Zero, Zero, Zero),update)))), tpe=Error, msg=None, causes=List(), directCause=Some(java.lang.RuntimeException: found version conflict(s) in library dependencies; some are suspected to be binary incompatible:
2022.08.28 17:04:12 INFO  [error] 
2022.08.28 17:04:12 INFO  [error]   * org.scala-lang.modules:scala-parser-combinators_2.13:2.1.1 (early-semver) is selected over 1.1.2
2022.08.28 17:04:12 INFO  [error]       +- ch.epfl.scala:hello-world_2.13:1.0                 (depends on 2.1.1)
2022.08.28 17:04:12 INFO  [error]       +- org.apache.spark:spark-catalyst_2.13:3.3.0         (depends on 1.1.2)
2022.08.28 17:04:12 INFO  [error] 
2022.08.28 17:04:12 INFO  [error] 
2022.08.28 17:04:12 INFO  [error]   * org.scala-lang.modules:scala-parser-combinators_2.13:2.1.1 (early-semver) is selected over 1.1.2
2022.08.28 17:04:12 INFO  [error]       +- ch.epfl.scala:hello-world_2.13:1.0                 (depends on 2.1.1)
2022.08.28 17:04:12 INFO  [error]       +- org.apache.spark:spark-catalyst_2.13:3.3.0         (depends on 1.1.2)
2022.08.28 17:04:12 INFO  [error] 
2022.08.28 17:04:12 INFO  [error] 
2022.08.28 17:04:12 INFO  [error] this can be overridden using libraryDependencySchemes or evictionErrorLevel))), directCause=None)), directCause=None)), directCause=None)), directCause=None), Incomplete(node=Some(Task((taskDefinitionKey: ScopedKey(Scope(Select(ProjectRef(file:/media/joris/projects/learn-scala/my-hello-world/,my-hello-world)), Zero, Zero, Zero),update)))), tpe=Error, msg=None, causes=List(Incomplete(node=Some(Task((tags: Map(Tag(update) -> 1, Tag(network) -> 1), taskDefinitionKey: ScopedKey(Scope(Select(ProjectRef(file:/media/joris/projects/learn-scala/my-hello-world/,my-hello-world)), Zero, Zero, Zero),update)))), tpe=Error, msg=None, causes=List(), directCause=Some(java.lang.RuntimeException: found version conflict(s) in library dependencies; some are suspected to be binary incompatible:
2022.08.28 17:04:12 INFO  [error] 
2022.08.28 17:04:12 INFO  [error]   * org.scala-lang.modules:scala-parser-combinators_2.13:2.1.1 (early-semver) is selected over 1.1.2
2022.08.28 17:04:12 INFO  [error]       +- ch.epfl.scala:hello-world_2.13:1.0                 (depends on 2.1.1)
2022.08.28 17:04:12 INFO  [error]       +- org.apache.spark:spark-catalyst_2.13:3.3.0         (depends on 1.1.2)
2022.08.28 17:04:12 INFO  [error] 
2022.08.28 17:04:12 INFO  [error] 
[...]
2022.08.28 17:04:12 INFO  [error] this can be overridden using libraryDependencySchemes or evictionErrorLevel))), directCause=None)), directCause=None)), directCause=None)), directCause=None), Incomplete(node=Some(Task((taskDefinitionKey: ScopedKey(Scope(Select(ProjectRef(file:/media/joris/projects/learn-scala/my-hello-world/,my-hello-world)), Select(ConfigKey(compile)), Zero, Zero),scalacOptions)))), tpe=Error, msg=None, causes=List(Incomplete(node=Some(Task((taskDefinitionKey: ScopedKey(Scope(Select(ProjectRef(file:/media/joris/projects/learn-scala/my-hello-world/,my-hello-world)), Select(ConfigKey(compile)), Zero, Zero),scalacOptions)))), tpe=Error, msg=None, causes=List(Incomplete(node=Some(Task((taskDefinitionKey: ScopedKey(Scope(Select(ProjectRef(file:/media/joris/projects/learn-scala/my-hello-world/,my-hello-world)), Select(ConfigKey(compile)), Zero, Zero),scalacOptions)))), tpe=Error, msg=None, causes=List(Incomplete(node=Some(Task((taskDefinitionKey: ScopedKey(Scope(Select(ProjectRef(file:/media/joris/projects/learn-scala/my-hello-world/,my-hello-world)), Select(ConfigKey(compile)), Zero, Zero),scalacOptions)))), tpe=Error, msg=None, causes=List(Incomplete(node=Some(Task((taskDefinitionKey: ScopedKey(Scope(Select(ProjectRef(file:/media/joris/projects/learn-scala/my-hello-world/,my-hello-world)), Select(ConfigKey(compile)), Zero, Zero),scalacOptions)))), tpe=Error, msg=None, causes=List(Incomplete(node=Some(Task((taskDefinitionKey: ScopedKey(Scope(Select(ProjectRef(file:/media/joris/projects/learn-scala/my-hello-world/,my-hello-world)), Zero, Zero, Zero),update)))), tpe=Error, msg=None, causes=List(Incomplete(node=Some(Task((tags: Map(Tag(update) -> 1, Tag(network) -> 1), taskDefinitionKey: ScopedKey(Scope(Select(ProjectRef(file:/media/joris/projects/learn-scala/my-hello-world/,my-hello-world)), Zero, Zero, Zero),update)))), tpe=Error, msg=None, causes=List(), directCause=Some(java.lang.RuntimeException: found version conflict(s) in library dependencies; some are suspected to be binary incompatible:
2022.08.28 17:04:12 INFO  [error] 
2022.08.28 17:04:12 INFO  [error]   * org.scala-lang.modules:scala-parser-combinators_2.13:2.1.1 (early-semver) is selected over 1.1.2
2022.08.28 17:04:12 INFO  [error]       +- ch.epfl.scala:hello-world_2.13:1.0                 (depends on 2.1.1)
2022.08.28 17:04:12 INFO  [error]       +- org.apache.spark:spark-catalyst_2.13:3.3.0         (depends on 1.1.2)
2022.08.28 17:04:12 INFO  [error] 
2022.08.28 17:04:12 INFO  [error] this can be overridden using libraryDependencySchemes or evictionErrorLevel))), directCause=None)), directCause=None)), directCause=None)), directCause=None)), directCause=None)), directCause=None)), directCause=None)), directCause=None), Incomplete(node=Some(Task((taskDefinitionKey: ScopedKey(Scope(Select(ProjectRef(file:/media/joris/projects/learn-scala/my-hello-world/,my-hello-world)), Select(ConfigKey(test)), Zero, Zero),bloopInternalClasspath)))), tpe=Error, msg=None, causes=List(Incomplete(node=Some(Task(_)), tpe=Error, msg=None, causes=List(Incomplete(node=Some(Task((taskDefinitionKey: ScopedKey(Scope(Select(ProjectRef(file:/media/joris/projects/learn-scala/my-hello-world/,my-hello-world)), Select(ConfigKey(test)), Zero, Zero),classpathConfiguration)))), tpe=Error, msg=None, causes=List(Incomplete(node=Some(Task((taskDefinitionKey: ScopedKey(Scope(Select(ProjectRef(file:/media/joris/projects/learn-scala/my-hello-world/,my-hello-world)), Zero, Zero, Zero),update)))), tpe=Error, msg=None, causes=List(Incomplete(node=Some(Task((tags: Map(Tag(update) -> 1, Tag(network) -> 1), taskDefinitionKey: ScopedKey(Scope(Select(ProjectRef(file:/media/joris/projects/learn-scala/my-hello-world/,my-hello-world)), Zero, Zero, Zero),update)))), tpe=Error, msg=None, causes=List(), directCause=Some(java.lang.RuntimeException: found version conflict(s) in library dependencies; some are suspected to be binary incompatible:
2022.08.28 17:04:12 INFO  [error] 
2022.08.28 17:04:12 INFO  [error] 
2022.08.28 17:04:12 INFO  [error]   * org.scala-lang.modules:scala-parser-combinators_2.13:2.1.1 (early-semver) is selected over 1.1.2
2022.08.28 17:04:12 INFO  [error]       +- ch.epfl.scala:hello-world_2.13:1.0                 (depends on 2.1.1)
2022.08.28 17:04:12 INFO  [error]       +- org.apache.spark:spark-catalyst_2.13:3.3.0         (depends on 1.1.2)
2022.08.28 17:04:12 INFO  [error] 
2022.08.28 17:04:12 INFO  [error] 
2022.08.28 17:04:12 INFO  [error] this can be overridden using libraryDependencySchemes or evictionErrorLevel))), directCause=None)), directCause=None)), directCause=None)), directCause=None)), directCause=None)), directCause=None), Incomplete(node=Some(Task(_)), tpe=Error, msg=None, causes=List(Incomplete(node=Some(Task((taskDefinitionKey: ScopedKey(Scope(Select(ProjectRef(file:/media/joris/projects/learn-scala/my-hello-world/,my-hello-world)), Select(ConfigKey(compile)), Zero, Zero),externalDependencyClasspath)))), tpe=Error, msg=None, causes=List(Incomplete(node=Some(Task(_)), tpe=Error, msg=None, causes=List(Incomplete(node=Some(Task((taskDefinitionKey: ScopedKey(Scope(Select(ProjectRef(file:/media/joris/projects/learn-scala/my-hello-world/,my-hello-world)), Select(ConfigKey(compile)), Zero, Zero),managedClasspath)))), tpe=Error, msg=None, causes=List(Incomplete(node=Some(Task(_)), tpe=Error, msg=None, causes=List(Incomplete(node=Some(Task((taskDefinitionKey: ScopedKey(Scope(Select(ProjectRef(file:/media/joris/projects/learn-scala/my-hello-world/,my-hello-world)), Zero, Zero, Zero),update)))), tpe=Error, msg=None, causes=List(Incomplete(node=Some(Task((tags: Map(Tag(update) -> 1, Tag(network) -> 1), taskDefinitionKey: ScopedKey(Scope(Select(ProjectRef(file:/media/joris/projects/learn-scala/my-hello-world/,my-hello-world)), Zero, Zero, Zero),update)))), tpe=Error, msg=None, causes=List(), directCause=Some(java.lang.RuntimeException: found version conflict(s) in library dependencies; some are suspected to be binary incompatible:
2022.08.28 17:04:12 INFO  [error] 
2022.08.28 17:04:12 INFO  [error]   * org.scala-lang.modules:scala-parser-combinators_2.13:2.1.1 (early-semver) is selected over 1.1.2
2022.08.28 17:04:12 INFO  [error]       +- ch.epfl.scala:hello-world_2.13:1.0                 (depends on 2.1.1)
2022.08.28 17:04:12 INFO  [error]       +- org.apache.spark:spark-catalyst_2.13:3.3.0         (depends on 1.1.2)
2022.08.28 17:04:12 INFO  [error] this can be overridden using libraryDependencySchemes or evictionErrorLevel))), directCause=None), Incomplete(node=Some(Task((taskDefinitionKey: ScopedKey(Scope(Select(ProjectRef(file:/media/joris/projects/learn-scala/my-hello-world/,my-hello-world)), Select(ConfigKey(runtime)), Zero, Zero),classpathConfiguration)))), tpe=Error, msg=None, causes=List(Incomplete(node=Some(Task((taskDefinitionKey: ScopedKey(Scope(Select(ProjectRef(file:/media/joris/projects/learn-scala/my-hello-world/,my-hello-world)), Zero, Zero, Zero),update)))), tpe=Error, msg=None, causes=List(Incomplete(node=Some(Task((tags: Map(Tag(update) -> 1, Tag(network) -> 1), taskDefinitionKey: ScopedKey(Scope(Select(ProjectRef(file:/media/joris/projects/learn-scala/my-hello-world/,my-hello-world)), Zero, Zero, Zero),update)))), tpe=Error, msg=None, causes=List(), directCause=Some(java.lang.RuntimeException: found version conflict(s) in library dependencies; some are suspected to be binary incompatible:
2022.08.28 17:04:12 INFO  [error] 
2022.08.28 17:04:12 INFO  [error] 
2022.08.28 17:04:12 INFO  [error] 
2022.08.28 17:04:12 INFO  [error]   * org.scala-lang.modules:scala-parser-combinators_2.13:2.1.1 (early-semver) is selected over 1.1.2
2022.08.28 17:04:12 INFO  [error]       +- ch.epfl.scala:hello-world_2.13:1.0                 (depends on 2.1.1)
2022.08.28 17:04:12 INFO  [error]       +- org.apache.spark:spark-catalyst_2.13:3.3.0         (depends on 1.1.2)
2022.08.28 17:04:12 INFO  [error] 
2022.08.28 17:04:12 INFO  [error] 
2022.08.28 17:04:12 INFO  [error] this can be overridden using libraryDependencySchemes or evictionErrorLevel))), directCause=None), Incomplete(node=Some(Task((taskDefinitionKey: ScopedKey(Scope(Select(ProjectRef(file:/media/joris/projects/learn-scala/my-hello-world/,my-hello-world)), Select(ConfigKey(compile)), Zero, Zero),classpathConfiguration)))), tpe=Error, msg=None, causes=List(Incomplete(node=Some(Task((taskDefinitionKey: ScopedKey(Scope(Select(ProjectRef(file:/media/joris/projects/learn-scala/my-hello-world/,my-hello-world)), Zero, Zero, Zero),update)))), tpe=Error, msg=None, causes=List(Incomplete(node=Some(Task((tags: Map(Tag(update) -> 1, Tag(network) -> 1), taskDefinitionKey: ScopedKey(Scope(Select(ProjectRef(file:/media/joris/projects/learn-scala/my-hello-world/,my-hello-world)), Zero, Zero, Zero),update)))), tpe=Error, msg=None, causes=List(), directCause=Some(java.lang.RuntimeException: found version conflict(s) in library dependencies; some are suspected to be binary incompatible:
2022.08.28 17:04:12 INFO  [error] 
2022.08.28 17:04:12 INFO  [error]   * org.scala-lang.modules:scala-parser-combinators_2.13:2.1.1 (early-semver) is selected over 1.1.2
2022.08.28 17:04:12 INFO  [error]       +- ch.epfl.scala:hello-world_2.13:1.0                 (depends on 2.1.1)
2022.08.28 17:04:12 INFO  [error] this can be overridden using libraryDependencySchemes or evictionErrorLevel))), directCause=None), Incomplete(node=Some(Task((taskDefinitionKey: ScopedKey(Scope(Select(ProjectRef(file:/media/joris/projects/learn-scala/my-hello-world/,my-hello-world)), Select(ConfigKey(compile)), Zero, Zero),classpathConfiguration)))), tpe=Error, msg=None, causes=List(Incomplete(node=Some(Task((taskDefinitionKey: ScopedKey(Scope(Select(ProjectRef(file:/media/joris/projects/learn-scala/my-hello-world/,my-hello-world)), Zero, Zero, Zero),update)))), tpe=Error, msg=None, causes=List(Incomplete(node=Some(Task((tags: Map(Tag(update) -> 1, Tag(network) -> 1), taskDefinitionKey: ScopedKey(Scope(Select(ProjectRef(file:/media/joris/projects/learn-scala/my-hello-world/,my-hello-world)), Zero, Zero, Zero),update)))), tpe=Error, msg=None, causes=List(), directCause=Some(java.lang.RuntimeException: found version conflict(s) in library dependencies; some are suspected to be binary incompatible:
2022.08.28 17:04:12 INFO  [error] 
2022.08.28 17:04:12 INFO  [error]       +- org.apache.spark:spark-catalyst_2.13:3.3.0         (depends on 1.1.2)
2022.08.28 17:04:12 INFO  [error] 
2022.08.28 17:04:12 INFO  [error] 
2022.08.28 17:04:12 INFO  [error]   * org.scala-lang.modules:scala-parser-combinators_2.13:2.1.1 (early-semver) is selected over 1.1.2
2022.08.28 17:04:12 INFO  [error]       +- ch.epfl.scala:hello-world_2.13:1.0                 (depends on 2.1.1)
2022.08.28 17:04:12 INFO  [error]       +- org.apache.spark:spark-catalyst_2.13:3.3.0         (depends on 1.1.2)
2022.08.28 17:04:12 INFO  [error] this can be overridden using libraryDependencySchemes or evictionErrorLevel))), directCause=None)), directCause=None)), directCause=None)), directCause=None)), directCause=None)), directCause=None), Incomplete(node=Some(Task((taskDefinitionKey: ScopedKey(Scope(Select(ProjectRef(file:/media/joris/projects/learn-scala/my-hello-world/,my-hello-world)), Select(ConfigKey(compile)), Zero, Zero),bloopInternalClasspath)))), tpe=Error, msg=None, causes=List(Incomplete(node=Some(Task(_)), tpe=Error, msg=None, causes=List(Incomplete(node=Some(Task((taskDefinitionKey: ScopedKey(Scope(Select(ProjectRef(file:/media/joris/projects/learn-scala/my-hello-world/,my-hello-world)), Select(ConfigKey(compile)), Zero, Zero),classpathConfiguration)))), tpe=Error, msg=None, causes=List(Incomplete(node=Some(Task((taskDefinitionKey: ScopedKey(Scope(Select(ProjectRef(file:/media/joris/projects/learn-scala/my-hello-world/,my-hello-world)), Zero, Zero, Zero),update)))), tpe=Error, msg=None, causes=List(Incomplete(node=Some(Task((tags: Map(Tag(update) -> 1, Tag(network) -> 1), taskDefinitionKey: ScopedKey(Scope(Select(ProjectRef(file:/media/joris/projects/learn-scala/my-hello-world/,my-hello-world)), Zero, Zero, Zero),update)))), tpe=Error, msg=None, causes=List(), directCause=Some(java.lang.RuntimeException: found version conflict(s) in library dependencies; some are suspected to be binary incompatible:
2022.08.28 17:04:12 INFO  [error] 
2022.08.28 17:04:12 INFO  [error] 
2022.08.28 17:04:12 INFO  [error]   * org.scala-lang.modules:scala-parser-combinators_2.13:2.1.1 (early-semver) is selected over 1.1.2
2022.08.28 17:04:12 INFO  [error] 
2022.08.28 17:04:12 INFO  [error]       +- ch.epfl.scala:hello-world_2.13:1.0                 (depends on 2.1.1)
2022.08.28 17:04:12 INFO  [error]       +- org.apache.spark:spark-catalyst_2.13:3.3.0         (depends on 1.1.2)
2022.08.28 17:04:12 INFO  [error] 
2022.08.28 17:04:12 INFO  [error] 
2022.08.28 17:04:12 INFO  [error] this can be overridden using libraryDependencySchemes or evictionErrorLevel))), directCause=None)), directCause=None)), directCause=None)), directCause=None)), directCause=None), Incomplete(node=Some(Task((taskDefinitionKey: ScopedKey(Scope(Select(ProjectRef(file:/media/joris/projects/learn-scala/my-hello-world/,my-hello-world)), Zero, Zero, Zero),scalaInstance)))), tpe=Error, msg=None, causes=List(Incomplete(node=Some(Task(_)), tpe=Error, msg=None, causes=List(Incomplete(node=Some(Task((taskDefinitionKey: ScopedKey(Scope(Select(ProjectRef(file:/media/joris/projects/learn-scala/my-hello-world/,my-hello-world)), Zero, Zero, Zero),update)))), tpe=Error, msg=None, causes=List(Incomplete(node=Some(Task((tags: Map(Tag(update) -> 1, Tag(network) -> 1), taskDefinitionKey: ScopedKey(Scope(Select(ProjectRef(file:/media/joris/projects/learn-scala/my-hello-world/,my-hello-world)), Zero, Zero, Zero),update)))), tpe=Error, msg=None, causes=List(), directCause=Some(java.lang.RuntimeException: found version conflict(s) in library dependencies; some are suspected to be binary incompatible:
2022.08.28 17:04:12 INFO  [error] 
2022.08.28 17:04:12 INFO  [error]   * org.scala-lang.modules:scala-parser-combinators_2.13:2.1.1 (early-semver) is selected over 1.1.2
2022.08.28 17:04:12 INFO  [error]       +- ch.epfl.scala:hello-world_2.13:1.0                 (depends on 2.1.1)
2022.08.28 17:04:12 INFO  [error]       +- org.apache.spark:spark-catalyst_2.13:3.3.0         (depends on 1.1.2)
2022.08.28 17:04:12 INFO  [error] 
2022.08.28 17:04:12 INFO  [error] 
2022.08.28 17:04:12 INFO  [error] this can be overridden using libraryDependencySchemes or evictionErrorLevel))), directCause=None)), directCause=None)), directCause=None)), directCause=None)
2022.08.28 17:04:12 INFO  [error] this can be overridden using libraryDependencySchemes or evictionErrorLevel))), directCause=None)), directCause=None)), directCause=None)), directCause=None)), directCause=None)), directCause=None)), directCause=None), Incomplete(node=Some(Task((taskDefinitionKey: ScopedKey(Scope(Select(ProjectRef(file:/media/joris/projects/learn-scala/my-hello-world/,my-hello-world)), Zero, Zero, Zero),scalaInstance)))), tpe=Error, msg=None, causes=List(Incomplete(node=Some(Task(_)), tpe=Error, msg=None, causes=List(Incomplete(node=Some(Task((taskDefinitionKey: ScopedKey(Scope(Select(ProjectRef(file:/media/joris/projects/learn-scala/my-hello-world/,my-hello-world)), Zero, Zero, Zero),update)))), tpe=Error, msg=None, causes=List(Incomplete(node=Some(Task((tags: Map(Tag(update) -> 1, Tag(network) -> 1), taskDefinitionKey: ScopedKey(Scope(Select(ProjectRef(file:/media/joris/projects/learn-scala/my-hello-world/,my-hello-world)), Zero, Zero, Zero),update)))), tpe=Error, msg=None, causes=List(), directCause=Some(java.lang.RuntimeException: found version conflict(s) in library dependencies; some are suspected to be binary incompatible:
2022.08.28 17:04:12 INFO  [error] 
2022.08.28 17:04:12 INFO  [error]   * org.scala-lang.modules:scala-parser-combinators_2.13:2.1.1 (early-semver) is selected over 1.1.2
2022.08.28 17:04:12 INFO  [error]       +- ch.epfl.scala:hello-world_2.13:1.0                 (depends on 2.1.1)
2022.08.28 17:04:12 INFO  [error]       +- org.apache.spark:spark-catalyst_2.13:3.3.0         (depends on 1.1.2)
2022.08.28 17:04:12 INFO  [error] 
2022.08.28 17:04:12 INFO  [error] 
2022.08.28 17:04:12 INFO  [error] this can be overridden using libraryDependencySchemes or evictionErrorLevel))), directCause=None)), directCause=None)), directCause=None)), directCause=None)
2022.08.28 17:04:12 INFO  [warn] Removed stale /media/joris/projects/learn-scala/my-hello-world/.bloop/my-hello-world-test.json
2022.08.28 17:04:12 INFO  [warn] Removed stale /media/joris/projects/learn-scala/my-hello-world/.bloop/my-hello-world.json
2022.08.28 17:04:12 INFO  [success] Total time: 2 s, completed Aug 28, 2022, 5:04:12 PM
2022.08.28 17:04:13 INFO  time: ran 'sbt bloopInstall' in 11s
2022.08.28 17:04:13 INFO  Disconnecting from Bloop session...
2022.08.28 17:04:13 INFO  Shut down connection with build server.
2022.08.28 17:04:13 INFO  Shut down connection with build server.
2022.08.28 17:04:13 INFO  Attempting to connect to the build server...
2022.08.28 17:04:13 INFO  Bloop uses /home/joris/.jabba/jdk/adopt@1.11.0-11 defined at /home/joris/.bloop/bloop.json
2022.08.28 17:04:13 INFO  tracing is disabled for protocol BSP, to enable tracing of incoming and outgoing JSON messages create an empty file at /media/joris/projects/learn-scala/my-hello-world/.metals/bsp.trace.json or /home/joris/.cache/metals/bsp.trace.json
2022.08.28 17:04:13 INFO  Attempting to connect to the build server...
2022.08.28 17:04:13 INFO  Bloop uses /home/joris/.jabba/jdk/adopt@1.11.0-11 defined at /home/joris/.bloop/bloop.json
2022.08.28 17:04:13 INFO  tracing is disabled for protocol BSP, to enable tracing of incoming and outgoing JSON messages create an empty file at /media/joris/projects/learn-scala/my-hello-world/project/.metals/bsp.trace.json or /home/joris/.cache/metals/bsp.trace.json
2022.08.28 17:04:13 INFO  time: Connected to build server in 0.14s
2022.08.28 17:04:13 INFO  Connected to Build server: Bloop v1.5.3
2022.08.28 17:04:13 ERROR Empty build targets. Expected at least one build target identifier.
2022.08.28 17:04:13 ERROR Empty build targets. Expected at least one build target identifier.
2022.08.28 17:04:13 ERROR Empty build targets. Expected at least one build target identifier.
2022.08.28 17:04:13 ERROR Empty build targets. Expected at least one build target identifier.
2022.08.28 17:04:14 INFO  time: indexed workspace in 1.41s
2022.08.28 17:04:14 WARN  no build target for: /media/joris/projects/learn-scala/my-hello-world/src/main/scala/Main.scala
2022.08.28 17:04:16 INFO  time: code lens generation in 1.4s
```

#### Versions

- Scala: 2.13.8
- Java: OpenJDK 11.0.16
- Spark: 3.3.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is in the log:

```
2022.08.28 17:04:12 INFO  [error] Couldn't run bloopGenerate for my-hello-world-test. Cause:
2022.08.28 17:04:12 INFO  [error]   * org.scala-lang.modules:scala-parser-combinators_2.13:2.1.1 (early-semver) is selected over 1.1.2
2022.08.28 17:04:12 INFO  [error]       +- ch.epfl.scala:hello-world_2.13:1.0                 (depends on 2.1.1)
2022.08.28 17:04:12 INFO  [error] Incomplete(node=Some(Task(_)), tpe=Error, msg=None, causes=List(Incomplete(node=Some(Task(_)), tpe=Error, msg=None, causes=List(Incomplete(node=Some(Task((tags: Map(Tag(update) -> 1, Tag(network) -> 1), taskDefinitionKey: ScopedKey(Scope(Select(ProjectRef(file:/media/joris/projects/learn-scala/my-hello-world/,my-hello-world)), Zero, Zero, Zero),updateClassifiers)))), tpe=Error, msg=None, causes=List(Incomplete(node=Some(Task((taskDefinitionKey: ScopedKey(Scope(Select(ProjectRef(file:/media/joris/projects/learn-scala/my-hello-world/,my-hello-world)), Zero, Select(updateClassifiers), Zero),classifiersModule)))), tpe=Error, msg=None, causes=List(Incomplete(node=Some(Task((taskDefinitionKey: ScopedKey(Scope(Select(ProjectRef(file:/media/joris/projects/learn-scala/my-hello-world/,my-hello-world)), Zero, Zero, Zero),update)))), tpe=Error, msg=None, causes=List(Incomplete(node=Some(Task((tags: Map(Tag(update) -> 1, Tag(network) -> 1), taskDefinitionKey: ScopedKey(Scope(Select(ProjectRef(file:/media/joris/projects/learn-scala/my-hello-world/,my-hello-world)), Zero, Zero, Zero),update)))), tpe=Error, msg=None, causes=List(), directCause=Some(java.lang.RuntimeException: found version conflict(s) in library dependencies; some are suspected to be binary incompatible:
2022.08.28 17:04:12 INFO  [error]       +- org.apache.spark:spark-catalyst_2.13:3.3.0         (depends on 1.1.2)
```

`spark-sql_2.13` depends on `spark-catalyst_2.13` and it depends on `scala-parser-combinators_2.13` of particular version (1.1.2) which is in conflict with your earlier version requirement for it. If you're happy with `scala-parser-combinators_2.13/1.1.2`, you can simply remove the first library dependency line from `build.sbt`.

Comment: Removing `libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-parser-combinators" % "2.1.1"` works like a charm indeed. Thanks!